# How to load images in Google Colab notebook using Tensorflow from mounted Google drive

Tags: tensorflow, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

In a Google Colab notebook, I have my Google drive mounted and can see my files. 
I'm trying to load a zipped directory that has two folders with several picture files in each.

I followed an example from the Tensorflow site that has an example on how to load pictures, but it's using a remote location.
Here's the site - https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images

Here's the code from the example that works:

```
data_root_orig = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
                                        fname='flower_photos', untar=True)
data_root = pathlib.Path(data_root_orig)
print(data_root)
```

Here's the revised code where I tried to reference the zipped directory from the mounted Google drive:

```
data_root_orig = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin='/content/gdrive/My Drive/TrainingPictures/',
                                         fname='TrainingPictures_Car', untar=True)
data_root = pathlib.Path(data_root_orig)
print(data_root)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: unknown url type: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/TrainingPictures/'
```

It's obviously expecting a URL instead of the path as I've provided.
I would like to know how I can load the zipped directory as provided from the Google drive.

Comment: Try `file:///content/gdrive/My Drive/TrainingPictures/` or something along those lines

Comment: Adding `file://` beginning to the url worked for me. @YoloSwaggins Can write your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, no need to use **tf.keras.utils.get_file()**, Only **Path** is enough.

Here 2 ways to do that

First:  `!unzip -q 'content/gdrive/My Drive/TrainingPictures/TrainingPictures_Car.zip'`

it will be unzipped on '/content/'

```
import pathlib
data = pathlib.Path('/content/folders_inside_zip') 
count = len(list(data.glob('*/*.jpg')))
count
```

Second: 
if archive already unzipped in google drive:

```
import pathlib
data = pathlib.Path('/content/gdrive/My Drive/TrainingPictures/') 
count = len(list(data.glob('*.jpg')))
count
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it actually worked by removing all imports and libraries and just setting the path as a string. The file has to be uploaded into the google colab.

```
content_path = "cat.jpg"
```

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked with file:///content/(filename)